# Join the List and the Data frame for matching list elements in Python

Tags: dataframe

I have a list =[a,b]  and

Dataframe as below

[image]

If the text in the 'Text column' matches  with List, then need to add additional column matchedItem

So output should be

[image]

Please suggest on this..How to get this output after the join (with exact match and partial match)..

also alternatively output in another dataframe(partial match)
[image]

Code
[image]

To resolve

I am trying something like this one

df["kpiName"] = getKPIName(df1.text.str)
kp1=['a','b']

def getKPIName (str):
    return [kp1.index(x) for x in kp1 if str in x]

But this results in
error
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not StringMethods

Comment: Which language (python, r, etc.)? Can you add a reproducible data sample (beyond just images which do nothing)? Have you tried anything before, can you share your existing code?

Comment: Thank You, I have tried using the join of dataframe and the list as below    dfList = pd.concat([df1.assign(kp1=i) for i in kpi], ignore_index=True)
print(dfList)

#df2 =  df1.loc[

Comment: Can you share the actual code and programming language? Because right now it is impossible for me to say why join did not work.

Comment: I am updating it in question

Answer (score 1):

The question is presented in a somewhat confusing fashion. However, I'm assuming OP has a dataframe setup something like this:

```
import pandas
data = { 'No': [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], 'Text': [ 'a', 'ab', 'b', 'bd' ] }
df = pandas.DataFrame( data )
```

In addition to the `df` file, OP has a `kpi` list consisting of `'a'` and `'b'`. There is also a `mask` variable, which I am assuming was meant to catch all cases where the `df.Text` is equal to either `'a'` or '`b`'. This is where the first mistake is. The way OP wrote that line would match cases where the character `a` is in any part of the element. In other words `'a' in 'ab'` is True. I suspect, OP wanted that statement to be False, which meant it needs to be written as `'a' == 'ab'` which would be false. I fixed it in the lines below:

```
kpi = [ 'a', 'b' ]
mask = df['Text'].apply( lambda x: any( item for item in kpi if item.lower() == x ) )
```

Basically I changed the `item.lower() in x` to `item.lower() == x`. Next, OP indicated that there should be a new column called `matchedItem`, which duplicates the `df.Text` when there was a match and `'----'` when there was not a match. Given the `mask` variable that OP had written, this can be done simply as such:

```
df[ 'matchedItem' ] = '----'
df.matchedItem[ mask ] = df.Text[ mask ]
```

In other words, first I set `'----'` as the default value for all the elements in column `matchedItem`. Next, I copy over the elements from column `Text` only for the rows identified in the `mask` variable. This results in the following output for `print( df )`:

```
   No Text matchedItem
0   1    a           a
1   2   ab        ----
2   3    b           b
3   4   bd        ----
```

There's a number of things that are unclear on the asking of this question (e.g. did OP really want to set mismatches as `'----'`? Is `No` supposed to be an index or a separate column? etc.), but hopefully this answer will guide OP towards the desired result.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for response

Comment: This works for the exact match df.matchedItem[ mask ] = df.Text[ mask ] but need this output in another dataframe with the partial match as well.. updated the question as above